# How do you use (GNU) make's "simply expanded" variables in build rules and not get the last definition?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a complicated set of rules I need to write to generate a rather large number of "parameterised" output files and thought that, rather than expand them all out by hand, I could repeatedly "include" a template file with sets of rules and use (GNU)make's facility for allowing ["simply expanded"](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_toc.html#TOC59) variables to avoid the pain.

(*In the past I've always been using the "recursively expanded" variable approach, so this is new to me*)

As a trivial example of what I *thought* would work, I tried putting the following in a Makefile

```
Targ:=A
Param1:=Pa
Param2:=Qa
$(Targ):
    @echo expect A, get $(Targ), Target is $@. Params are $(Param1) and $(Param2) 

Targ:=B
Param1:=Pb
Param2:=Qb
$(Targ):
    @echo expect B, get $(Targ), Target is $@. Params are $(Param1) and $(Param2) 

Targ:=C
Param1:=Pc
Param2:=Qc
$(Targ):
    @echo expect C, get $(Targ), Target is $@. Params are $(Param1) and $(Param2)
```

The eventual plan was to replace the rules with an include file containing dozens of different rules, each referencing the various "parameter" variables.

However, what I get is...

```
prompt> make A
expect A, get C, Target is A. Params are Pc and Qc


prompt> make B
expect B, get C, Target is B. Params are Pc and Qc
```

Essentially, unlike each rule's target, which *is* picking up the intended definition,  the `$(Targ)`, `$(Param1)`, and `$(Param2)` in each rule's *command* is instead being run with the *final* definition.

Does anyone know how to prevent this, i.e. how do you force the command to use the definition at the time it is encountered in the Makefile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple vs recursive expansion makes no difference here; regardless of which you use you'll see the same behavior.  A GNU make variable is *global* and obviously can have only one value.

You have to understand when variables are expanded.  The documentation provides a [detailed description](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reading-Makefiles.html) of this.  Targets and prerequisites are expanded *when the makefile is read in*, so the value of `Targ` as the makefile is being parsed is used.

Recipes are expanded *when the recipe is to be invoked*, which is not until after all makefiles are parsed and make starts to build targets.  At that time of course the variable `Targ` has its last set value.

Without knowing what your makefile really does it's hard to suggest an alternative.  One option is to use target-specific variables:

```
Targ := A
$(Targ): LocalTarg := $(Targ)
$(Targ):
        @echo expect A, get $(LocalTarg), Target is $@
```

Another option is to use constructed variable names:

```
Targ := A
Targ_$(Targ) := $(Targ)
$(Targ):
        @echo expect A, get $(Targ_$@), Target is $@
```

Comment: Thanks for the link on when variables are expanded - that was the piece of documentation  jigsaw I hadn't found. 
I can't use the target-based expansion simply because I have multiple "parameters" I need to set. Looks like I'll have to resort to building multiple different include files from a template using, say, sed.

Comment: I very much doubt that you have to do that but I can't say more based on the information provided.  You may want to take a look at this set of blog posts (start with the oldest one): http://make.mad-scientist.net/category/metaprogramming/

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for answering my own question, but I now realised it is possible to solve the issue I was having by running make recursively.

E.g. if the parameter variables for the rules are Targ, Param1 and Param2 then

```
#Set up "default" values for the parameters (As @madscientist points out, 
#these will safely be overridden by the defs on the @(make) commands below

Targ=XXXXXXXXXX
Param=XXXXXXXXXX
Param2=XXXXXXXXXX
Recursing=

#
# define N (==3) templated rule(s)
#
$(Targ)%a:
    @echo Run Combo_a $(Targ) $(Param1) $(Param2) $@

$(Targ)%b:
    @echo Run Combo_b $(Targ) $(Param2) $(Param1) reversed $@

$(Targ)%c:
    @echo Run Combo_c  $(Param1) $(Targ) $(Param2) mixed again $@

#
#Enumerate "M" (==2) sets of parameters, 
# (Except if we are already recursing because unrecognised targets may cause
# it to descend forever)
#
ifneq ($(Recursing), Yes)
Set1%:
    @$(MAKE) Targ=Set1 Param1=foo Param2=bar Recursing=Yes $@

Set2%:
    @$(MAKE) Targ=Set2 Param1=ray Param2=tracing Recursing=Yes $@
endif
```

This then allows N*M different combos for N+M typing cost.
eg. (removing messages from make re recursion)

```
>make Set1.a
Run Combo_a Set1 foo bar Set1.a

>make Set2.c
Run Combo_c ray Set2 tracing mixed again Set2.c
```

Comment: You don't technically need to use `?=` here; assignment on the command line will always take precedence over any assignment in the makefile regardless of whether `?=` is used or not.

Comment: Thanks!  Perhaps being paranoid, but I'll simplify the answer.
BTW much appreciate the meta-programming links you posted. I'm somewhat into to Makefiles that bootstrap themselves with self-generated includes :-)